# Activate 3 monitors with GeForce GT610 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I struggle trying to activate 3 monitors on my GeForce GT 610. I was following the walkthrough provided by burntsushi on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/13vkup/3_monitors_on_linux_with_nvidia_gtx_670_can_it_be/) in a really close thread. But since the question is closed I cannot ask my question directly there.
In following I post the output resulting in following the steps:
xrandr -q brings me the following 3 connected outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x >8192 DVI-I-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1920x1080 60.0 + 1680x1050 60.0
1280x1024 75.0 60.0
1440x900 75.0 59.9
1280x800 59.8
1152x864 75.0
1024x768 75.1 70.1 60.0
832x624 74.6
800x600 72.2 75.0 60.3 56.2
640x480 75.0 72.8 66.7 60.0
720x400 70.1
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm 1920x1080 60.0+ 50.0 50.0 50.0 59.9
1920x1080i 60.1 50.0 60.0
1680x1050 59.9
1280x1024 75.0 60.0
1440x900 75.0 59.9
1280x800 59.9
1152x864 75.0
1280x720 60.0 50.0 59.9
1440x576i 50.1
1024x768 75.1 70.1 60.0
1440x480i 60.1 60.1
832x624 74.6
800x600 72.2 75.0 60.3 56.2
720x576 50.0
720x480 60.0 59.9
640x480 75.0 72.8 66.7 60.0 59.9
720x400 70.1
VGA-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm 1920x1080 60.0+ 1680x1050 60.0
1280x1024 75.0 60.0
1440x900 75.0 59.9
1280x800 59.8
1152x864 75.0
1024x768 75.1 70.1 60.0
832x624 74.6
800x600 72.2 75.0 60.3 56.2
640x480 75.0 72.8 66.7 60.0
720x400 70.1
```

When I try to set them according to burntsushi I get an error: xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --auto --output VGA-1 --auto --right-of DVI-I-1 --output HDMI-1 --auto --right-of VGA-1

```
xrandr: cannot find crtc for output HDMI-1
```

I don't know why this error occurs. I also found out about a [bug concerning this error message](https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr/pull/16) but didn't find it helpful.

Has anyone a suggestion what I can try next to activate the third display? Thanks guys!

Oh btw I already tried different combinations of activated displays. It does not matter which display gets activated at last.

I also posted this question on reddit but since i do not know how much these communities overlap I'm reposting it here. As I do not have enough reputation I cannot link the question from reddit here. So if you're interested in the discussion (which is not existent right now) such search for: "3 Monitors on Ubuntu 14.04 with GeForce GT 610"

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether you want to activate three monitors on the NVidia or do you want to use one monitor connected to the onboard graphics adapter.

I have three monitors on GeForce 210. Two are connected to the NVidia and the third to onboard adapter. I was not able to set it up with NVidia drivers, but I did not spend to much time trying. I tried it with nouveau driver (http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) which is the default NVidia driver in Ubuntu. I had not problems setting it up with nouveau.

NVidia driver works faster and better but I chose a tradeoff to be able to use three monitors.

Comment: I want all three displays connected to the Nvidia. I'll wait for some more feedback. If noone can help me, I will give nouveau a shot but I actually bought this GPU just for the ability to control all 3 displays.

Comment: looks like the third monitor is not possible, per [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/how-to-enable-three-monitors-nvidia-gt-610-cannot-find-crtc-for-output-4175466905/)